# Python3 detect that a file's encoding is not as specified in open statement

Tags: python-3.x

When opening a file and specifying encoding, is there a way to detect that the file you're opening  is not encoded in the encoding specified.
NOTE: I'm not using 'with' here to try and make example clear
e.g.

```
    try:
        WorkF = open(MYFILE, 'r', encoding = 'utf-8')
    except IOError as error:
        print(f'Error opening file {MYFILE} : {error}')
    sys.exit(1)
```

How do I detect here that the file is not in utf-8.

This is to avoid reading a compressed file, for example, which will nastily fall over.
Filenames are specified on the CLI, and sometimes users give a gzipped file instead of the gunzipped version.

i.e. trying to avoid.
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)

The only way I can think of doing this is to wrap the entire processing of the contents in a try: except UnicodeDecodeError: block, but that is ugly.

Perhaps there is a way to detect before opening it ?

Answer (score 0):

So the most pythonic way is to just try to open it and catch the error, you can then present the user with information indicating they cannot use your program with compressed files, it is not clear why you would consider that "ugly". If you attempt to identify all the variations of magic bits for compressed or other binary files you will undoubtedly miss some anyway.

```
try:
    with open(MYFILE, 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as WorkF:
        for line in WorkF:
            print(line)
except UnicodeDecodeError:
    print('Not for use with compressed files.')
```